# How to update redux store with react suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-suspense, react-concurrent

In following code, `Sample` uses a `async` function to get some data. I will be using that data to update the Redux store so any component can access the `username` within the application.

```js
const resource = fetchData();

function Sample() {
    // throws a promise when retrieving data
    const name = resource.read();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(setUsername(name));

    const username = useSelector((state) => state.username);

    return <div>User: {username}</div>;
}

<Suspense fallback="loading....">
    <Sample />
</Suspense>
```

Here, lets assume there is no way my application can proceed without the username. Well, `<Suspense>` at parent level achieves that up until data are fetched from the resource. However, there is a slight gap from Redux event dispatch to `<Sample>` component re-render where is displays `User:` instead of `loading....` (event don't force the re-render immediately so `username` is empty). So I will see following content in the web page in the same order

`loading....` --> `User:` --> `User: Srinesh`

So my requirement is to show `loading....` until store is updated. On the web page, I'm expecting to see,

`loading....` --> `User: Srinesh`

Is there a way to achieve this without using another condition at `<Sample>` component level to show `loading....` if the username is `null`?

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that dispatching in the middle of component rendering logic is a side effect, and you must never do that.

A safer place to put that would be in a `useLayoutEffect` hook, which will dispatch as soon as the component is done rendering, but force a synchronous re-render before the browser has a chance to paint.  That way you won't see the flash.